# How do you fix "runtimeError: package fails to pass a sanity check" for numpy and pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, numpy

This is the error I am getting and, as far as I can tell, there is nothing useful on the error link to fix this.

> RuntimeError: The current Numpy installation
> (`'...\\venv\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py'`) fails to pass a
> sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime.

See this issue for more information: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1207405/fmod-after-an-update-to-windows-2004-is-causing-a.html

I have tried multiple versions of Python (3.8.6 and 3.9.0) and numpy and pandas. I am currently using PyCharm to do all this.

Answer (score 193, accepted):

This error occurs when using python3.9 and numpy1.19.4
So uninstalling numpy1.19.4 and installing 1.19.3 will work.

---

**Edit**

As of January 5th 2021 numpy version `1.19.5` is out and appears to solve the problem.

Comment: How to downgrade it using pip?

Comment: @ShaidaMuhammad pip install numpy==1.19.3

Comment: Dammit `numpy`, test before you release please. This isn't beta

Comment: I'm using Python 3.7.5 and got this error too (numpy 1.19.4). Downgrading numpy to 1.19.3 indeed prevents the error from happening.

Comment: @NoName: We did test, and the bug is in windows itself. 1.19.3 was an attempt at fixing this by using a different version of OpenBLAS that works around the problem, but that version did not work correctly on linux.

Comment: I had the same issue with python 3.8 and 'pip install numpy==1.19.3 --upgrade' solved it ! Thanks !

Comment: Same issue with Python 3.8

Comment: @Eric While it is clearly a problem with the Windows libraries, this just doesn't seem like a great solution. The link that shows up when the sanity check fails doesn't even provide any workaround for the time being.

Comment: @Eric the silent majority appreciates the incredible work you and all numpy authors are doing and doesn't feel like a simple to google downgrade fix to make numpy work on a broken OS is too much to do once in a decade in return

Answer (score 57):

I am using Python 3.7, anyway the same solution suggested here helped me.

```
pip install numpy==1.19.3
```

Actually the link informed https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1207405/fmod-after-an-update-to-windows-2004-is-causing-a.html shows the given solution. It seems to be a bug in Visual Studio, which remains unsolved up to this date.

Comment: Technically, it's a bug in the UCRT (the universal redistributable C/C++ runtime), not Visual Studio itself.

Answer (score 28):

Just install `numpy==1.19.3`
I am using python 3.9

Answer (score 20):

As per the discussion on the link you provided, a numpy dev answered:

> NumPy has released a bugfix 1.19.3 to work around this issue. The
> bugfix broke something else on Linux, so we had to revert the fix in
> release 1.19.4, but you can still install the 1.19.3 via pip install
> numpy==1.19.3.

So, if you need requirements that work for both Linux and Windows, you'll need to use PEP508:

```
numpy==1.19.3; platform_system == "Windows"
numpy>=1.19.4; platform_system == "linux"
```

Comment: Can probably do `numpy>=1.19.4` on linux

Comment: You should use upper case "Linux" instead: `numpy>=1.19.4; platform_system == "Linux"`

Comment: And you can check platform_system by following code:`import platform;platform.system()` see: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#environment-markers

Answer (score 12):

It's a bug of `numpy 1.19.4` that fails with all python versions. Use the previous version to *solve* the problem, so by terminal:

```
pip install numpy==1.19.3
```

Comment: 1.9.3 is failing to install on my Windows

Comment: @JariTurkia It is 1.19.3.

Answer (score 10):

Rolling back to numpy 1.19.3 worked for me on python 3.8.6

Answer (score 5):

The workaround is provided in the link mentioned in question.

The developer [mattip](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/users/129980/8c2d36f2-fc1f-4f5c-b8d2-df53cfec2951.html) mentions below in the workaround suggested by him:

1. Uninstall numpy.( Most probably it's 1.19.4)
2. pip install numpy==1.19.3

This worked for me.

My configuration:OS-Win10,Anaconda Distribution,python=3.7

Answer (score 1):

Why hasn't anyone posted the difference between 1.19.3 and 1.19.4.

The problematic numpy init code is:

```
def _win_os_check():
    """
    Quick Sanity check for Windows OS: look for fmod bug issue 16744.
    """
    try:
        a = arange(13 * 13, dtype= float64).reshape(13, 13)
        a = a % 17  # calls fmod
        linalg.eig(a)
    except Exception:
        msg = ("The current Numpy installation ({!r}) fails to "
                "pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime. "
                "See this issue for more information: "
                "https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1207405/fmod-after-an-update-to-windows-2004-is-causing-a.html")
        raise RuntimeError(msg.format(__file__)) from None

if sys.platform == "win32" and sys.maxsize > 2**32:
    _win_os_check()

del _win_os_check
```

This code section doesn't exist in 1.19.3; that's the only difference.

Comment: There's another more important difference between the 1.19.3 and 1.19.4 wheels installed by pip - the version of OpenBLAS they are built with. If you remove that code from numpy 1.19.4, then instead of numpy not importing, you'll get a numpy that produces incorrect results and/or crashes randomly. The correct fix is to switch to 1.19.3, which contains a "safe" build of OpenBLAS.

Answer (score 1):

I had to follow below steps to fix this error as everyone else has suggested above.

My environment details: Windows 10 64 bit, with Python 3.9.0 installed. I have installed pip 20.3.1

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy==1.19.3
```

I am posting my powershell command line output for your reference(may be useful to someone).

PS C:\Users\XXXX> pip uninstall numpy

Found existing installation: numpy 1.19.4

Uninstalling numpy-1.19.4:

Would remove:

```
c:\python39\lib\site-packages\numpy-1.19.4.dist-info\*

c:\python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\*

c:\python39\scripts\f2py.exe
```

Proceed (y/n)? y

Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.19.4

PS C:\Users\XXXX> pip install numpy==1.19.3

Collecting numpy==1.19.3

Downloading numpy-1.19.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (13.3 MB)

```
 |████████████████████████████████| 13.3 MB 6.4 MB/s
```

Installing collected packages: numpy

Successfully installed numpy-1.19.3