# RuntimeError while using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I just want to start working with pandas in python but I cant go further. When  write the first samplecode it gives me an error. RuntimeError: The current Numpy installation ('c:\users\... .py') fails to pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime.

I already have numpy==1.19.4 and pandas==1.1.4

What can I do or what should I do???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64654805/how-do-you-fix-runtimeerror-package-fails-to-pass-a-sanity-check-for-numpy-an and https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/1241964/view.html

Comment: Rolling back to numpy 1.19.3. That should do the trick.