# Python- Not able to import pyautogui

Tags: python, numpy, runtime-error, pyautogui, python-3.9

```
Python 3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.


>>> import pyautogui
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 305, in <module>
    _win_os_check()
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 302, in _win_os_check
    raise RuntimeError(msg.format(__file__)) from None
RuntimeError: The current Numpy installation ('C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py') fails to pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime.
>>>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you fix "runtimeError: package fails to pass a sanity check" for numpy and pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64654805/how-do-you-fix-runtimeerror-package-fails-to-pass-a-sanity-check-for-numpy-an)

Answer (score 0):

I was using Numpy 1.19.4 in Python 3.9 and error occured for me. So downgrade your numpy installation to 1.19.3 (First Uninstall PyAutoGUI then Numpy and then re-install Numpy 1.19.3 with `pip install numpy==1.19.3` and then PyAutoGUI)

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem