# I was installing matplotlib through pip. I got the following error

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.630]
(c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\SAMBIT SAGAR>pip install matplotlib
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached matplotlib-3.3.2.tar.gz (37.9 MB)
 ** On entry to DGEBAL parameter number  3 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DGEHRD  parameter number  2 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DORGHR DORGQR parameter number  2 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DHSEQR parameter number  4 had an illegal value
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\sambit sagar\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\SAMBIT SAGAR\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a10hcyr2\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\SAMBIT SAGAR\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a10hcyr2\\matplotlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\SAMBIT SAGAR\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-84jnrskq'
         cwd: C:\Users\SAMBIT SAGAR\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a10hcyr2\matplotlib\
    Complete output (62 lines):
    WARNING: The wheel package is not available.

    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options; suppress output with --quiet.

    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
      matplotlib: yes [3.3.2]
          python: yes [3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC
                      v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]]
        platform: yes [win32]
     sample_data: yes [installing]
           tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
          macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]

    running egg_info
    creating C:\Users\SAMBIT SAGAR\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-84jnrskq\matplotlib.egg-info
    writing C:\Users\SAMBIT SAGAR\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-84jnrskq\matplotlib.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\SAMBIT SAGAR\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-84jnrskq\matplotlib.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing namespace_packages to C:\Users\SAMBIT SAGAR\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-84jnrskq\matplotlib.egg-info\namespace_packages.txt
    writing requirements to C:\Users\SAMBIT SAGAR\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-84jnrskq\matplotlib.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to C:\Users\SAMBIT SAGAR\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-84jnrskq\matplotlib.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\SAMBIT SAGAR\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-84jnrskq\matplotlib.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\SAMBIT SAGAR\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a10hcyr2\matplotlib\setup.py", line 242, in <module>
        setup(  # Finally, pass this all along to distutils to do the heavy lifting.
      File "c:\users\sambit sagar\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\sambit sagar\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\sambit sagar\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\sambit sagar\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\sambit sagar\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 298, in run
        self.find_sources()
      File "c:\users\sambit sagar\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 305, in find_sources
        mm.run()
      File "c:\users\sambit sagar\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 536, in run
        self.add_defaults()
      File "c:\users\sambit sagar\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 572, in add_defaults
        sdist.add_defaults(self)
      File "c:\users\sambit sagar\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\sdist.py", line 228, in add_defaults
        self._add_defaults_ext()
      File "c:\users\sambit sagar\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\command\sdist.py", line 311, in _add_defaults_ext
        build_ext = self.get_finalized_command('build_ext')
      File "c:\users\sambit sagar\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 299, in get_finalized_command
        cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
      File "c:\users\sambit sagar\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
        self.finalize_options()
      File "C:\Users\SAMBIT SAGAR\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a10hcyr2\matplotlib\setup.py", line 88, in finalize_options
        self.distribution.ext_modules[:] = [
      File "C:\Users\SAMBIT SAGAR\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a10hcyr2\matplotlib\setup.py", line 91, in <listcomp>
        for ext in package.get_extensions()
      File "C:\Users\SAMBIT SAGAR\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a10hcyr2\matplotlib\setupext.py", line 345, in get_extensions
        add_numpy_flags(ext)
      File "C:\Users\SAMBIT SAGAR\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a10hcyr2\matplotlib\setupext.py", line 469, in add_numpy_flags
        import numpy as np
      File "c:\users\sambit sagar\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 305, in <module>
        _win_os_check()
      File "c:\users\sambit sagar\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 302, in _win_os_check
        raise RuntimeError(msg.format(__file__)) from None
    RuntimeError: The current Numpy installation ('c:\\users\\sambit sagar\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py') fails to pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime. See this issue for more information: 
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: There is a link at the end of the error message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you fix "runtimeError: package fails to pass a sanity check" for numpy and pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64654805/how-do-you-fix-runtimeerror-package-fails-to-pass-a-sanity-check-for-numpy-an)

Comment: It says `WARNING: The wheel package is not available.`. In many cases this means that the Python version you are using is newer than what the package supports. Try lower python version (3.8.x). And with Python 3.9.x, the fix is probably found behind the link Michael provided.