# Problem to run spaCy and add language models

Tags: python, numpy, installation, spacy

I have problems installing spaCy in Python 3.9
I changed to Python 3.7 and could make the installation with no problem, until I used the python command for language models downloading.
In fact, I can't import spaCy running console. This is the error

```
>>> import spacy
 ** On entry to DGEBAL parameter number  3 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DGEHRD  parameter number  2 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DORGHR DORGQR parameter number  2 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DHSEQR parameter number  4 had an illegal value
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from thinc.neural.util import prefer_gpu, require_gpu
  File "C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\thinc\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import numpy  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 305, in <module>
    _win_os_check()
  File "C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 302, in _win_os_check
    raise RuntimeError(msg.format(__file__)) from None
RuntimeError: The current Numpy installation ('C:\\Users\\Alberto\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py') fails to pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime. See this issue for more information: 
>>> 

Previously, trying to download the language model I got error as well:
 C:\Users\Alberto>python -m spacy download es_core_news_sm
 ** On entry to DGEBAL parameter number  3 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DGEHRD  parameter number  2 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DORGHR DORGQR parameter number  2 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DHSEQR parameter number  4 had an illegal value
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 142, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from thinc.neural.util import prefer_gpu, require_gpu
  File "C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\thinc\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import numpy  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 305, in <module>
    _win_os_check()
  File "C:\Users\Alberto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 302, in _win_os_check
    raise RuntimeError(msg.format(__file__)) from None
RuntimeError: The current Numpy installation ('C:\\Users\\Alberto\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py') fails to pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime. See this issue for more information:
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you fix "runtimeError: package fails to pass a sanity check" for numpy and pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64654805/how-do-you-fix-runtimeerror-package-fails-to-pass-a-sanity-check-for-numpy-an)

Comment: Yes, it is the answer. Thank you!