# problem with numpy ('module' object is not callable), ( fails to pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime.)

Tags: python, numpy, permissions, anaconda, reset

I got this error trying to install another package: the current Numpy installation fails to pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime. Ive checked the problem and it seems to occur using the newest version of numpy (1.19.4). I then downgraded and it still didnt work. I then tried a lot of deinstalling, reinstalliung and whatnot until it seems I destroyed my numpy completely. Even the simplest functions do not work anymore. Right now im back to version 1.19.4, but when I try to use it, it says the object is not callable. Example:

```
import numpy as np

print(np.random(10))
```

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

It might be because of permissions? I got these messages while reinstallilng numpy:
"ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Zugriff verweigert: 'C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\~-mpy\.libs\libopenblas.NOIJJG62EMASZI6NYURL6JBKM4EVBGM7.gfortran-win_amd64.dll'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions."

"ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Zugriff verweigert: 'C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\~andas\_libs\algos.cp38-win_amd64.pyd'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions."

RuntimeError: The current Numpy installation ('C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-h9d1jjmf\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\**init**.py') fails to pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime. See this issue for more information:

I even reinstalled anaconda but I think the oldest numpy just reinstalls itself. Which is the easiest way to reset my numpy completely? (I tried the obvious pip uninstall numpy and pip install numpy...)

Answer (score 0):

You want `np.random.random(10)`. `np.random` is the module, `np.random.random` is the function.

Documentation: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.random.html

Comment: okay, oops. But the other problem still stands ( fails to pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime.)) Any other solution than downgrading? im using python 3.9

Comment: @Elias I googled that error and found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64654805/how-do-you-fix-runtimeerror-package-fails-to-pass-a-sanity-check-for-numpy-an), why did none of those solutions work for you?

Comment: yes, I saw that one too. I tried that but I still got some errors. I think I found the solution: The downgrading didnt properly work because I dont have admin rights on my work computer. So something went wrong in between uninstalling and reinstalling.

Comment: Now I installed numpy 1.19.3 locally but still get the sanity check fail.... I dont get it