# When I using matplotlib module I am getting run time error

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

```
#Importing pyplot
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#Plotting to our canvas
plt.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,1])
```

#Showing what we plotted

```
plt.show()
```

** On entry to DGEBAL parameter number  3 had an illegal value
** On entry to DGEHRD  parameter number  2 had an illegal value
** On entry to DORGHR DORGQR parameter number  2 had an illegal value

** On entry to DHSEQR parameter number  4 had an illegal value

The current Numpy installation fails to pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime.

#This is the error that is coming.

Comment: so what is the error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you fix "runtimeError: package fails to pass a sanity check" for numpy and pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64654805/how-do-you-fix-runtimeerror-package-fails-to-pass-a-sanity-check-for-numpy-an)

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error on windows.
Try the previous version of numpy:

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy==1.19.3
```

[Source and relevant for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64654805/how-do-you-fix-runtimeerror-package-fails-to-pass-a-sanity-check-for-numpy-an)