# RuntimeError when installing rioxarray

Tags: python, numpy, runtime-error

As I tried to install rioxarray by:

```
pip install rioxarray
```

I got the following error:

```
RuntimeError: The current Numpy installation (...) fails to pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime.
```

A bit of search ended me up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64654805/how-do-you-fix-runtimeerror-package-fails-to-pass-a-sanity-check-for-numpy-an) which suggests downgrading numpy to 1.19.3.

But it didn't work for me.

Are there any further suggestions?

OS: window 10, python:3.8.5

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you fix "runtimeError: package fails to pass a sanity check" for numpy and pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64654805/how-do-you-fix-runtimeerror-package-fails-to-pass-a-sanity-check-for-numpy-an)

Comment: @DavidBuck As I mentioned above unfortunately no it doesn't!

Comment: I mention it as the error message "RuntimeError: The current Numpy installation (...) fails to pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime." is ONLY produced by Numpy 1.19.4, so you may have had two separate issues. That error message must have been related to the Numpy version.

Comment: Yes. You are right. After downgrading numpy to 1.19.3 I don't remember if the error message was the same as before. However since the title is about an issue in installing rioxarray and not numpy fail to pass sanity check , the process I went through to solve it can be useful for anybody who face with the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading over the error message I figured out that the problem actually returns to one of rioxarray's dependencies called *rasterio* which can not be installed by pip. It is even mentioned in its [document](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) that it should be installed by *.whl* file.

By the way I did all of the following steps to solve this problem. I don't know which one is crucial but doing them as a whole solved mine.

1. Although I had *GDAL* installed, I upgrade it to *3.1.4* by its wheel file [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal).
2. I installed [fiona 1.8.18](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#fiona)
3. I installed [rasterio 1.1.8](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#rasterio)
4. Then `pip install rioxarray`

**Note 1:** For those who don't know how to install .whl file, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file) might be helpful. All you need to do is just run `pip install <filename>.whl` in the file directory.

**Note 2:** Thanks to [lww](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7056842/lww) there is no need of doing so in anaconda environment and installing rioxarray works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using `numpy==1.19.3` will not help in this case.
rioxarray can be installed, if you don't mind using anaconda.
The installation works without any warnings, conda takes care of all dependencies.

```
> conda create -n myproj
> conda activate myproj
> conda install -c conda-forge rioxarray

> python 
Python 3.9.1 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Dec  9 2020, 01:07:06) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>import rioxarray
>>>print(rioxarray.__version__)
0.1.1
```

Comment: Thank you. It works well using conda. But there should be a reason why this error occurs.

Comment: Looks like the fault lies with people who develop these libraries. End users like us can't  do much about it.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me (I use python3 and pip3):

- `pip3 install virtualenv`
- `python3 -m virtualenv myproj`
- `source myproj/bin/activate`
- `pip3 install rioxarray`