# Errors using pylab and numpy in Python 3.8.0

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, module

I have installed the required modules, matplotlib, numpy, and pillow, but when I try to use pylab in Python 3.8.0 a long error message is displayed. Similar issues arise when trying to use other related modules such as numpy or matplotlib.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pylab
  File "C:\Users\candl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "C:\Users\candl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 107, in <module>
    from . import cbook, rcsetup
  File "C:\Users\candl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\candl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 305, in <module>
    _win_os_check()
  File "C:\Users\candl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 302, in _win_os_check
    raise RuntimeError(msg.format(__file__)) from None
RuntimeError: The current Numpy installation ('C:\\Users\\candl\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py') fails to pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime. See this issue for more information:
```

Does anyone have suggestions regarding these issues?

Comment: You copied the text *"See this issue for more information: "*, but seem to have left off the rest of the sentence.

Comment: Did you look into [How do you fix “runtimeError: package fails to pass a sanity check” for numpy and pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64654805/how-do-you-fix-runtimeerror-package-fails-to-pass-a-sanity-check-for-numpy-an)?

Comment: Thank you, I read that post and installing numpy 1.19.3 fixed the issue

Comment: FYI: You should probably [not use pylab](https://matplotlib.org/api/index.html#module-pylab) anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
pip uninstall numpy
```

and then:

```
pip install numpy==1.19.3
```

A google search showed me that this error occurs when using python3.9 and **numpy1.19.4** So uninstalling numpy1.19.4 and installing **1.19.3** will work.

I know that your python version is older than 3.9 but this should ***still work.***

For more reference:

https://github.com/int-brain-lab/iblenv/issues/111

[How do you fix "runtimeError: package fails to pass a sanity check" for numpy and pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64654805/how-do-you-fix-runtimeerror-package-fails-to-pass-a-sanity-check-for-numpy-an)