# Ignore specific package version when running setup.py

Tags: python, numpy, setup.py

I'm running into the error discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64654805/how-do-you-fix-runtimeerror-package-fails-to-pass-a-sanity-check-for-numpy-an) when running setup.py: numpy 1.19.4 fails to install due to a windows bug. The current workaround is to use numpy 1.19.3 instead. However, I'm trying to run a setup.py file that doesn't list numpy directly as a dependency, but uses several packages that has numpy as a sub-dependency.

Because of this, I cannot directly pin numpy to 1.19.3. In this scenario, is there a simple way to get the install script working? In other words: how can I modify the setup.py file so that it won't install any package (versions) that has numpy 1.19.4 as a dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [available dependency relations](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#relationships-between-distributions-and-packages) include `!=`

```
numpy!=1.19.4
```

Comment: thanks, that looks to be what I need. Where can I add this requirement to make sure it is respected when running `setup.py`? I tried adding it to `setup_requires` and `install_requires` with no luck

Comment: `install_requires=['numpy!=1.19.4']` works for me, and currently gets me 1.20.0rc2 on MacOS with Python 3.7.2.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me when numpy is a sub-dependency. pip still seems to install numpy 1.19.4 when other packages depend on numpy

Comment: turns out this wasn't the root cause of my issues, so no answer to this question could have worked. Nevertheless, thanks again for your help.